# GnuCash: Reimbursable expenses paid by credit card

Tags: gnucash

In my business we buy a number of things for client projects with the company credit card. I understand that to have them show up on the client's bill I need to use the Vendor-Bill process. But when I go to pay that Bill, the credit card accounts are not available choices for where to post the payment. All I have is cash accounts and A/P. At the time of the purchase, I am accruing a credit card payable so I would like to pay the bill without running every credit card expense through A/P then transferring the A/P balance to the credit card account. Is it possible to change a setting to allow credit cards as payment sources for Vendor Bills?

Answer (score 1):

GNUCash won't show 'Credit Card' type accounts in "Process Payment", as of v.2.6.1. A workaround is to create another

```
Liabilities:Credit Card
```

account of type A/Payable.

Then, transfer the operations you want to pay via "Process Payment" to this new account. It should be visible now. A drawback is that you have split your current Credit Card debt, which makes it harder to track.
Alternatively you may wish to only use this new account for all your credit card related expenses.

Another alternative is processing payments for these purchases manually to keep the 'credit card' accounts consistent.